# Laravel 5.7 custom URL with multiple parameter

Tags: laravel, routes, href, laravel-5.7

I have this problem where i need to get this kind of url `localhost:8000/purchaseOrder/3/purchase/1` 
if i typed it manually it worked but when i make the laravel automatically create the url it got error and end up with `localhost:8000/purchaseOrder/$data-%3Eid/payable/$p-%3Eid`

this are my routing

```
Route::get('/purchaseOrder/{id}/payable/{he}', 'AjaxController@purchaseOrder');
```

this are my controller (so far all i wanted is just respond to the url i gave)

```
function purchaseOrder($id,$he)
{
  echo $id." | ".$he;
}
```

this are my view

```
<a href="{{ url('purchaseOrder/$data->id/payable/$p->id') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm my-1" name="button">Create Purchase Order</button></a><br>
```

Comment: you need to concatenate your variables with the url `'purchaseOrder/'.$data->id.'/payable/'.$p->id.'` with the `.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change view code :

```
<a href="{{ url('purchaseOrder/'.$data->id.'/payable/'.$p->id.') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm my-1" name="button">Create Purchase Order</button></a><br>
```

another way is this:

set name for route

```
Route::get('/purchaseOrder/{id}/payable/{he}', 'AjaxController@purchaseOrder')->name('purchaseOrder');
```

and in view:

```
<a href="{{ route('purchaseOrder',[$data->id,$p->id]) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods to achieve this.

(1) Use **route()** method: Pass route name

```
<a href="{{ route('purchaseOrder',['id' => $data->id,'he' => $p->id]) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm my-1" name="button">Create Purchase Order</button></a>
```

(2) Use **url()** method: pass URL of the route

```
<a href="{{ url('purchaseOrder/'.$data->id.'/payable/'.$p->id.') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm my-1" name="button">Create Purchase Order</button></a><br>
```

Please update your route with name for first **route()** method

```
Route::get('/purchaseOrder/{id}/payable/{he}', 'AjaxController@purchaseOrder')->name('purchaseOrder');
```

Comment: Naming of the route must be the same with the purchaseOrder or i could be anything?

Comment: Yes, you can use anything like (->name('xyz')). but in the route() method, you should pass xyz like (route('xyz')). @MartinChristopher